# Slim Route seems to reset static variables

Tags: php, slim

I use a Slim route to call `RabbitBroker::setup()` and track its response.

The setup method will always go ahead and do the init proccess. It never returns the "already setup" message. I tried to use `RabbitBroker::$isSetup` instead of `self::$isSetup` .. Keeps forgeting the value.. Am I going crazy here?

```
class RabbitBroker
{     
    private static $isSetup = false; 

    public static function setup() {

        if (self::$isSetup) return "Connection was set already setup";

        self::$isSetup = true;

        // do some init...

        return "Connection is now set by init"
    }

}
```

Comment: For me it all works fine, when I call `RabbitBroker::setup()` twice it returns different strings.

Comment: @jmattheis do you call it via a Slim Route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to share the value of a static variable between requests. 
PHP is stateless (like HTTP), because if this, each script execution has its own static variables.

So setting a static variable only set it for the current request and not for the following requests.